# Unable to push to git using git desktop app - can't find explorer.exe

Tags: git, github

I'm using the GitHub Desktop app to git a project I do with others.
I tried to make a test commit (just a text file) and commit works fine, but I'm unable to push. 
What happens is I click push, then file explorer pops up. The git app just says

> Find: 'explorer.exe': no such file or directory.

and it's stuck there forever, even if the change is just a line of txt file (and the whole project currently is just an empty android project). 
I'm sending a screenshot on the issue.

[image]

I **did** download the git app as well, not just the desktop.
I would like to ask for assistance to be able to push my commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but it turned out I had some mining malware in my system.

If this is also your case, check following (or look also at [github issue](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3604)):

- before`find: 'explorer.exe': no such file or directory.` appears, for a moment there blinks also `find: 'SoundMixer.exe': no such file or directory.`
- if you start `cmd`, it just blinks
- after few times you tried to push and close the app, there are hanging processes of `Sound Mixing Utility` and the github app itself
- you have `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe` present

I followed [this guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9fb738ab-2f3d-4a07-ac8a-173d63a47f87/cmd-not-working-due-to-an-error-the-error-occurs-on-practically-everything?forum=win10itprogeneral) to remove it and now it is working again.